# regex to insert space in a variety of instances

Tags: php, regex

I'm programmatically cleaning up data as it's being inputted and need to extract the quantity information for the item.  For each item, there needs to be a space between the quantity number and quantity unit.  Sometimes it includes a decimal, and sometimes a dash (-) is unhelpfully right next to the quantity information.  The dash should either have a space inserted between it and the quantity information or be removed entirely.

The regex I've included below will handle the Milk entry, but none of the others.

**Note**: sometimes a serial number is at the beginning of the string (`$str`), which is why the quantity units must be included in the `preg_replace`.

```
$str = "Chicken 4 lbs.";

$str = "Cream of Mushroom Soup 10.4oz";

$str = "4XY Milk 1gal";

$str = "Leaf Spinach -12oz";

$str = "5QB Bananas -6.2lb.";

$str = preg_replace('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[g|g.|oz|oz.|lb|lb.|gal|gal.|mL|mL.|kg|kg.|un|un.|tab|tab.])/',' ', $str);
```

EDIT: in testing your answers (All of which are brilliant, btw!), I've come up with an added dimension: IF the dash (-) is IMMEDIATELY preceded by an alphanumeric character, I do NOT want to create a space after it.

```
$str = "Route US-66 4 lb";
```

Comment: shorten that to `(?<=[0-9])(?=(g|oz|lb|gal|mL|kg|un|tab)\.?)` `?` makes the `.` optional.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you misunderstand how character classes and `|` work.

When you put characters in a character class, the `|` loses its meaning (and so do a lot of other characters, except `-` can gain a new meaning, for character ranges) and will match the literal character `|`. Instead, use parentheses. Then, I would make the string a little shorter by putting an optional period at the end:

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=(?:g|oz|lb|gal|mL|kg|un|tab)\.?)
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/tX0cB3)

Is that what you're looking for?

---

**EDIT**:

For the dash, you could maybe add this bit:

```
(?<=-)(?=[0-9])
```

And to combine it with the above (also removing period as per @Ron in comments):

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=g|oz|lb|gal|mL|kg|un|tab)|(?<=-)(?=[0-9])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/uE1pF8)

---

**EDIT2**:

As per update, to prevent adding a space before a dash preceeded by an alphanumeric character:

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=g|oz|lb|gal|mL|kg|un|tab)|(?<=\B-)(?=[0-9])
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/vF1rQ2)

Comment: I believe the terminal \.? to be unnecessary, which would make the non-capturing group superfluous.

Comment: @Jerry the link you sent me is really helpful, but I still need to deal with the dash.  I either need it separated with a space or removed.  What do you think is the most effective way to do that?  Thanks!

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Very true. I didn't think about that, oops!

Comment: @Jerry is it possible to handle the situation i explained in my edit?  I may be overreaching

Answer (score 1):

Proper regex:

```
(?<= -)(?=\d+)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])
```

Your PHP:

```
$str = "Leaf Spinach -12oz";
echo preg_replace('/(?<= -)(?=\d+)|(?<=\d)(?=[a-z])/', ' ', $str);
```

**Output**:

```
Leaf Spinach - 12 oz
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/zZ7jH9)

Comment: Fails on:  5QB Bananas -6.2 lb.  (note no space after dash; space after number)

Comment: Since yours now seems to be all inclusive, I will remove my answer.  Although I would suggest that yours could possibly be made more robust by adding the specific units to the lookahead.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld is there a way to handle the situation i described in my edit?  thanks!

Comment: I believe if you change the first lookbehind to:  (?<=\B-)  that will do the trick.  So I would use something like:  (?<=\B-)(?=\d+(?:\.\d+)\s*(?=lb|oz|gal|kg))|(?<=\d)(?=lb|oz|gal|kg)  (adding appropriate alternation for other units of measure), and including case insensitive option.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
(?<=[0-9])(?=(g|oz|lb|gal|mL|kg|un|tab)\.?)
```

[image]